Dynamically evaluated keys doesn't thrown error in typescript
type XForce = {
  max:number
  min:number
}

let gMan :XForce = {
  max:23,
  min:21
}

const t=Math.random();

//1.
gMan={
  ...gMan,
  [t<0.5?"t":"w"]:3 // doesn't throw error even though t and w are both invalid
}

//2.
gMan={
  ...gMan,
  ["w"]:2// throws error
}


The possibilities of key for gMan is only t and w which are not valid in XForce
Using key w but this time it throw error

I tried creating type for only keys and then creating const with that type and assign dynamic value to it.
type XForce = {
  max:number
  min:number
}

let gMan :XForce = {
  max:23,
  min:21
}

const t=Math.random();

// --------
type gManKeys = keyof XForce
const key:gManKeys = t<0.5?"t":"w" // throws error here
gMan={
  ...gMan,
  [key]:3 
}
// --------


gMan={
  ...gMan,
  ["w"]:2// throws error
}

But I expecting typescript to detect error without this additional change, so there is no mistake of specifying key name by dev.

Does TypeScript support this? Have you read it somewhere in the specification? What is your question? Please use only tags that a relevant to the question. This question is unrelated to JavaScript.

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920 and the q/a linked above.
